# Spring-boot ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, resourcebundle

I have created a class `TestReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` by extending `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` in my application and implemented like this.

```
public class TestReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

//....
}


@Bean
public TestReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {

    String messagesPath = "C:/messages";

    TestReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new  TestReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("file:" + messagesPath);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(Charsets.UTF_8.name());

    return messageSource;
  }
```

But when I'm changing the properties file values, save and reload the page I'm getting the old values not new values without restarting the server.

My properties files are not in class path.

What could be reason and how can I reload it. Any solution will be appreciated.

I'm using `spring-boot 1.4.4.RELEASE` .

Comment: What's the location of your properties files?
note: A value of "0" will check the last-modified timestamp of the file on every message access. Do not use this in a production environment!

Comment: its somewhere in disc for example c:/messages/

Comment: well, I used your way and fetched properties from an external file, it worked fine when updating the properties file. Can you provide more details and sources?

Comment: @Maddy could you please provide me your sample source code?

Comment: I just reused your code. MessageConfig.java is the spring config file. 

https://gist.github.com/madhawa-bandara/42372fbda9b60cb7aa28fbcd1fc9fa60

Fetch the properties loaded:
applicationContext.getMessage("test",null, Locale.US);

Comment: change the properties runtime and observed ,did you get the updated messaged without restarting the server?

Comment: Yeah they did. that's why I wanted to check the full source.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for me.

```
@Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource  resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        String messageFolderPath = propertyLocation + "/" + "i18n";
        resource.setBasename("file:"+messageFolderPath+"/messages");
        resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        resource.setCacheSeconds(10);
        return resource;
    }
```